# Coroutine couldn't be started because the the game object is inactive

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer, coroutine

I'm getting an error of "Coroutine couldn't be started because the the game object 'TimeOutWarningDialog' is inactive!" but I'm unsure why I'm getting this error.

Just to give a rundown of the code:

1. I'm looking for inactivity in GameManger.Update()
2. If inactive for a period of time I call GameManager.ShowRestartWarning()
3. TimeOutWarningDialog gets SetActive to true
4. I check if the object is active before calling StartRestartTimer(), if (timerInstance.activeSelf == true) StartRestartTimer();
5. I call startTimer() in CountdownTimer class

I'm setting the object that I'm instatiating to 'active' before I call the startTimer function which includes the coroutine. what am I doing wrong here?
 any help would be great!!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // Create Singleton
    public static GameManager instance = null;

    // Set Default Background Color
    public Color defaultColor;

    // Restart variables
    private Vector3 prevMousePosition;
    public GameObject timeOutWarningDialog;
    public GameObject restartDialog;
    public float countdownLength;
    public float timeUntilCountdown;

    // Game Controller
    private GameObject canvas;
    private GameObject gameManager;
    public GameObject timerInstance;
    public Object startingScene;
    private Scene currentScene;

    // File System List of Folders
    public List<string> folders;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = this;
        else if (instance != null)
            Destroy(gameObject);

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

        gameManager = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameManager");
    }

    void Start()
    {       
        prevMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.anyKeyDown || Input.mousePosition != prevMousePosition)
            if(currentScene.name != startingScene.name)
                StartGameTimer();
        prevMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    // GAME TIMER

    void StartGameTimer()
    {
        //  Debug.Log("Game Timer Started");
        CancelInvoke();

        if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Timer") == null)
            Invoke("ShowRestartWarning", timeUntilCountdown);
    }

    void ShowRestartWarning()
    {
        canvas = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas");

        timerInstance = Instantiate(timeOutWarningDialog);
        timerInstance.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
        timerInstance.SetActive(true);

        if (timerInstance.activeSelf == true)
            StartRestartTimer();
    }

    void StartRestartTimer()
    {
        CountdownTimer countdownTimer = timeOutWarningDialog.GetComponent<CountdownTimer>();
        countdownTimer.startTimer(countdownLength);

        CancelInvoke();
        Invoke("RestartGame", countdownLength);
    }

    void RestartGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(startingScene.name);

        Debug.Log("Game Restarted");
        Debug.Log("Current Scene is " + currentScene.name + ".");
    }

    void DestroyTimer()
    {
        Destroy(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Timer"));
    }
}
```

then I'm calling startTimer in the CountdownTimer class below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class CountdownTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float countdownLength;
    public Text timerText;
    public bool stop = true;
    private float minutes;
    private float seconds;

    public void startTimer(float from)
    {
        stop = false;
        countdownLength = from;
        Update();
        StartCoroutine(updateCoroutine());
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (stop) return;
        countdownLength -= Time.deltaTime;

        minutes = Mathf.Floor(countdownLength / 60);
        seconds = countdownLength % 60;
        if (seconds > 59) seconds = 59;
        if (minutes < 0)
        {
            stop = true;
            minutes = 0;
            seconds = 0;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator updateCoroutine()
    {
        while (!stop)
        {
            timerText.text = string.Format("{0:0}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
            Debug.Log(string.Format("{0:0}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe one of its ancestors, like `canvas.transform`, is inactive?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this method:

```
void StartRestartTimer()
{
    CountdownTimer countdownTimer = timeOutWarningDialog.GetComponent<CountdownTimer>();
    countdownTimer.startTimer(countdownLength);

    CancelInvoke();
    Invoke("RestartGame", countdownLength);
}
```

You start the coroutine first and then invoke `RestartGame` to load another scene. So the object with the coroutine gets destroyed.

---

I can't give you the solution because it requires more knowledge regarding your scenes but you may want to try additive scene loading.